# Pass a parameter from page to controller without apex:param in visualforce

Tags: salesforce, visualforce, apex

I'm trying to pass a parameter from a Visualforce page to the controller in an apex:actionfunction however I'm facing a strange dilemma.

The only way the apex:param works with the action function is if there is a rerender attribute on it.  Unfortunately I can't use a rerender because I also have an apex:inputfile on the page; which causes an error if there is a rerender attribute.

Any ideas how to pass a parameter to the controller without using an apex:param.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are so particular about not using `apex:param`, then you should consider using **JavaScript Remoting** to pass parameters from Visualforce to Apex.

Otherwise if you are okay to use `apex:param` but the problem is only with `apex:inputFile` tag, then you should use `apex:actionRegion` tag.

I am not posting the complete code, but just giving you the references below. Hope the below links will help:

[Passing a value from Visualforce Page to Controller](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/36580/passing-a-value-from-visualforce-page-to-controller)

[apex:actionRegion - Visualforce Developer Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_actionRegion.htm)

[JavaScript Remoting - Visualforce Developer Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_js_remoting.htm)

Comment: I haven't completely validated that everything works, but it looks like wrapping the action:function in an action region works.  I no longer get an error from SF about the rerender and the parameter seems to be set in my controller. Thanks.